# CodingBat Array-maxMirror

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve this problem from CodingBat.

> We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous
>   elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in
>   reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in {1, 2, 3, 8,
>   9, 3, 2, 1} is length 3 (the {1, 2, 3} part). Return the size of the
>   largest mirror section found in the given array.
>
> maxMirror([1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1]) → 3 maxMirror([1, 2, 1, 4]) → 3
>   maxMirror([7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1]) → 2

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums)
{
  int count = 0;
  int max = 0;
  int min = 0;

  String abc = "";

  for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++)
  {
   abc += nums[i];
  }//

  for(int i=0, k = abc.length(); i<abc.length(); i++, k--)
  {
    for(int j=i, l = abc.length()-i; j<abc.length(); j++, l--)
    {
      if(abc.substring(i,j).equals(abc.substring(k,l)))
        min = abc.substring(i,j).length();

        if(min > max)
        max = min;

     }
  }
  count = max;

  return count;

}
```

I thought inserting the all elements of an array into a string is a very good idea, since string class has its own functions such as substring.

I think my algorithm to this problem is simple, flexible and reliable but it doesn't work as i thought. I'm getting exception errors which complains about the bounds of the string.

What should i do?

Comment: Your substring method fails as soon as one of the integers is greater than 9.  Try this algorithm: 1) Reverse the int array.  2) Look for the longest sequence in the original array and the reversed array.

Comment: Also as Gilbert Le Blanc mentioned you only need to search for the the duplicate numbers since the duplicates can be the only candidates.

Answer (score 0):

I also toyed with the idea of a reverse/compare algo, but it's still going into O(n^..), so I settled on this solution. The idea here is for each int element moving forward in the array, we begin to iterate backward from the end. If we get a match, we go into the while()loop, continuing to compare and increment our size variable until they no longer match. From there, it's a simple matter of comparing to our max variable, updating max to either itself or var size,(whichever is higher) eventually returning max.

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int left = 0; left < nums.length; left++) {
        for(int right = nums.length -1; right >= 0; right--) {
            int size = 0;
            int i = left;
            int j = right;
            while(i < nums.length && j >= 0 && nums[i] == nums[j]) {
                size++;
                i++;
                j--;
          } max = Math.max(max, size);
        }
    } return max;
}
```

Comment: Explaining your solution will make your answer more clear. Please try to have a description of your solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).